# Storage $_SESSION['user'] on a var

Tags: php, string, session, var

Is it possible to store a literal string saying: `$_SESSION[user]` in a var?

I tried

```
$user = "$_SESSION['user']";
```

But that resulted in an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Then I tried:

```
$user = "$_SESSION[user]";
```

If I echo `$user` i get a number 19, why?

Why do I need this? Because I'm using `fwrite` so I'm creating a new PHP file with an HTML that I already wrote, so my code its something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['nameofph'])) {

  $fname = fopen($_POST['nameofph'].'.php','w+');
  fwrite($fname, $fdata);
  fclose($fname);
}
```

I do not know if I explain it well, the point is I need to store that "string" in the var `$user`.

Comment: $user = $_SESSION['user']; ?

Comment: Is the $_SESSION['user'] getting stored as a string? did u check that ..

Comment: `$user = "$_SESSION['user']";`   or use `$user = $_SESSION['user']; ` should work `$user = "$_SESSION[user]"; ` is totally wrong.

Comment: People desperate for accepted answers @PrafullaKumarSahu lol

Comment: @Tredged I think this can be flagged as off-topic for  the problem that can not be produced or small spelling mistake

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Agree'd.

Comment: @Gil you can accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store `$_SESSION["user"]` as string into variable by using single quote at start & end and double quote before `INDEX`.

Try

```
$user = '$_SESSION["user"]';
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e3ac813bf59f95c67983e281fd7a293a7b64660)

Comment: is he really going to use single quote  here `'$_SESSION["user"]' `?  I do not see it is going to work.single does not parse variable, you need no quotes or double quotes .

Comment: Down votes for what?

Comment: You are again wrong .

Comment: THANKS, that solved my problem, and @PrafullaKumarSahu that was the point, i didnt need parse a var, i just needed that "string".

Comment: so why you need to put any quote just use `$_SESSION["user"]` or `$_SESSION['user']` . that's is enough.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I have added demo link into my question.

Comment: what your demo is doing is trating the $_SESSION['user'] as string.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yes it is. You can see `$_SESSION["user"]` as output string.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu OP wants to store `$_SESSION["user"]` as value of variable not value of `$_SESSION["user"]` as value of variable.

Comment: @Gil I'm glad it works for you. You can click on trick mark if you found my answer useful.

Comment: @Hassaan now, I think may be you are correct , can you edit your answer , I will remove my down vote there.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this to store session value into a variable

```
$user = (string)$_SESSION['user'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about..

```
$user = "\$_SESSION[user]";
```